# Physics Based Inverse Kinematics Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an FPS set up where there is simply an arm model pointed out the front of the player. Initially, using the animation rigging package, I made it such that the hand and subsequent joints followed a target. The issue with this is that when moving the target into a wall, for example, the arm will follow. There are two problems with this; one, obviously, being the lack of realism and two being that the game I am making is founded and themed by phyics interactions. To combat this I attempted two things; first, I tried to attach a collider to the target but this lead to strange movement and still some clipping with physical objects. Then, I tried implementing a script that fires raycasts that, every frame, check whether you are interacting with an object but this was expensive and inconsistent.

I have an idea which I feel may work and this is by having a combination of configurable joints, colliders and rigidbodies between the joints of the arm; acting as a ragdoll. Then, the hand would move to the target via interpolation and the upper joints would follow due to the physics joints. I have found this difficult to implement as it is not resistant/stiff like arms and the elbow merely flops around, it also feels very strange.

Suggestions, help or perhaps improvement of the idea I have will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!